# Удалить всё до определенного слова в текстовом файле

Tags: java

Имеются текстовые файлы, в которых есть одно слово, которое используется только один раз.
Нужно удалить весь текст до этого слова.

Реализация в Java. Кто подскажет?

Спасибо. Реализовал сразу с записью в файл вот так:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException{
         Path path = Paths.get("test.txt");
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
        content = content.substring(content.indexOf("string6"), content.length());
        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
    }
}
```

Comment: Слово известно или его ещё нужно найти?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то это делается как-то так, как я это сделал ниже по тексту. Конечно, в зависимости от конкретной задачи код может измениться, я без понятния, для чего это Вам, поэтому предлагаю только то, о чем прочел в вопросе.

**Содержимое файла test.txt:**

```
string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
string6
string7
string8
```

**Реализация:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

...

File file = new File( "/home/user/test.txt" );

try (FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream( file );   
    InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(FIS,"UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ISR)) {

    String line;
    String text = "";

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          text += line;
    }

    //Удаляем все симфолы до ключевого слова, предположим это string6
    //Выведем ключевое слово + весь остальной текст из файла.
    System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf("string6"), text.length()));

    //Можем и перезаписать наш файл.
    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file)) {
       out.print(text.substring(text.indexOf("string6"), text.length()));
    } catch(IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Зачем же все содержимое в память-то читать?  
(тем более, что *string6* вполне может оказаться **частью другого слова** (например, `ABCstring6DEF`))

Comment: @avp, да, все так, как Вы говорите. Можно и нужно по другому реализовывать + с учетом конкретной задачи, но мне это делать за автора лень.

Comment: @avp, если хотите, напишите реализацию, я ее вставлю в свой ответ. :)

Answer (score 1):

Читайте исходный файл до искомого слова (запоминать весь текст не надо).

Остаток (текст после слова) переписываете во временный файл, который потом переименовываете в исходный (впрочем, для более системонезависимой программы лучше перед переименованием удалить исходный файл, [см. Class Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html))